# Ms Access locks me on the row after the start of data entry for update or insert, if VBA for "before / after update" is active

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm having a problem with MS Access where it's locking me inside the rows if I change any value from the row. So it only let me get out if I hit escape, loosing all of my changes. The curious part of it is that this behavior only occurs if there's an "after update / after insert" trigger in the VBA body of that form.

Here goes a sample of the VBA code for after / before update triggers:

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    If Form_update2.ComboItemization.Value = "LENS" Then
        Me.hpa_ccode_rule.Value = Me.hpa_inv_desc.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.hpa_hcpc_desc.Value = Me.hpa_inv_desc.Value
    Me.hpa_proc_code.Value = Me.hpa_plan.Value
    Me.hpa_hcpc_code.Value = Me.hpa_itemize_cat.Value
    Me.hpa_non_disc.Value = "D"
    Me.hpa_inv_box.Value = "N"

    If Left(Form_update2.Txt_Price_Type, 1) = "A" Then
        Me.hpa_dtl_aod.Value = "A"
        Me.hpa_rlp.Value = "P"
        Me.hpa_itm_aod.Value = Null
    ElseIf Left(Form_update2.Txt_Price_Type, 1) = "P" Then
        Me.hpa_dtl_aod.Value = Null
        Me.hpa_rlp.Value = "J"
        Me.hpa_itm_aod.Value = "P"
    ElseIf Left(Form_update2.Txt_Price_Type, 1) = "M" Then
        Me.hpa_dtl_aod.Value = Null
        Me.hpa_rlp.Value = "P"
        Me.hpa_itm_aod.Value = "M"
    End If
End Sub
```

Really thanks

Comment: Why isn't that AfterUpdate code in the BeforeUpdate? Why would two fields have the same data? It is not necessary to type .Value because that is the default property for data controls.

Comment: Hi, you're right about the after update. It was partially involved in the solution. Also, regarding the same data in multiple fields = 35+ years old system.

Comment: Don't think I've ever needed form Before and After update. I do data validation with control BeforeUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

fortunately, after trying even more, I got what was causing the error. But I don't know how to explain.

1. The ="Null" statements needed to be converted to =""
2. The "If Form_update2.ComboItemization.Value = LENS" needed to be replaced by "If Trim(Me.hpa_itemize_cat) = LENS".
3. Finally the "after update" block needed to be moved to the "before update".

Heres the final code:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Me.hpa_hcpc_desc.Value = Me.hpa_inv_desc.Value
Me.hpa_proc_code.Value = Me.hpa_plan.Value
Me.hpa_hcpc_code.Value = Me.hpa_itemize_cat.Value
Me.hpa_non_disc.Value = "D"
Me.hpa_inv_box.Value = "N"

If Left(Form_update2.Txt_Price_Type, 1) = "A" Then
    Me.hpa_dtl_aod.Value = "A"
    Me.hpa_rlp.Value = "P"
    Me.hpa_itm_aod.Value = ""
           
ElseIf Left(Form_update2.Txt_Price_Type, 1) = "P" Then
    Me.hpa_dtl_aod.Value = ""
    Me.hpa_rlp.Value = "J"
    Me.hpa_itm_aod.Value = "P"
    
ElseIf Left(Form_update2.Txt_Price_Type, 1) = "M" Then
    Me.hpa_dtl_aod.Value = ""
    Me.hpa_rlp.Value = "P"
    Me.hpa_itm_aod.Value = "M"
End If
 
If Trim(Me.hpa_itemize_cat) = "LENS" Then
    Me.hpa_ccode_rule.Value = Left(Me.hpa_inv_desc.Text, 15)
End If
End Sub
```

I hope someone can give best answers than mine, because I don't think my answer is complete. Once it misses the explanations for the above points 1 and 3.

Comment: I've never had difficulty setting a control/field to Null. I don't even allow empty string in fields. Why would you need Trim - does data have leading space?

Comment: I can't explain, the data doesn't have extra spaces, but just worked in this way. It also doesn't work with "Trim(Me.hpa_itemize_cat.value)" or with "Trim(Me.hpa_itemize_cat.text)". Sorry but I really don't know why. I hope someone could be able to explain it better than me. Then I'll mark as the right answer.

Comment: Doubtful can explain without directly examining data and db design. Code did not have `="Null"`, it had `=Null` which should work unless field is set as "Required" in table.